How to achieve text overlay with hover and variable highlighting in an input field?
I'm working on an Angular project where I need to overlay highlighted text within an input field. Specifically, I want to:

Highlight variables in the input, e.g., {{variableName}} should be visually distinct.
Display an overlay with additional information when hovering over
the variable.
Still allow users to interact with the input (e.g., place the cursor, type text), even if the variable is highlighted and interactive.

I've implemented a directive to mirror the text of the input into a div positioned over the input field, with a span around the variable to highlight it. Here's what I'm struggling with:

Handling mouse events: When I hover over the variable, I want to show an overlay. However, if I enable pointer-events on the overlay, it prevents the user from interacting with the input field itself (e.g., placing the cursor or typing).
Event propagation: I need to capture mouseover events on the variables but allow other mouse events to propagate to the input field.

Stackblitz sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mmdjbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-text-basic-demo.html

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working example with a stackblitz, along with what needs to be done on the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mmdjbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-text-basic-demo.html

you need to use pointer-events: none to allow the editing of input even if overlay is present. does that solve your problem?

when i set to none on overlay then overlay does not receive events which i would need as well

when you perform selection, you can add a class to the input element, that disables this CSS style, this will solve your issue. In your stackblitz I am unable to replicate this problem, let me know if you need help, but I need to stackblitz to have this problem happening. along with exact steps the replicate the issue.

in the stackblitz there is no dropdown opening for me to check it

its not implemented yet but the event should appear for the dropdown it works
but not for the overlaybox

when you select try adding the class to the input this will solve your issue.
